# I'm trying to make string parser but something is going wrong

Tags: c

I was trying to make a text parser which separates words in a string based on the space character. However, something is going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    //the string should end with a space to count the all words
    char name[30] = "hello world from jordan ";
    int start = 0;
    int end = strlen(name);
    int end_word = start;
    char full[20][20];

    memset(full, 0, 400);

    int number_of_words = 0;

    for (int w = 0; w < end; w++) {
        if (name[w] == ' ') {
            number_of_words++;
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < number_of_words) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (name[i] == ' ') {
                start = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = end_word; j < start; j++) {
            full[counter][j] = name[j];
        }

        end_word = start;
        start++;
        counter++;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
            printf("%c", full[x][y]);
        }

        printf("%d", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is the strange thing happening when I run the code:

```
 hello0 world1 from2 jor3dan45678910111213141516171819
```

the first three words are being initialized in the right way but the fourth is not and I don't know why this is happening.

I want an explanation for the problem and if possible I want a more efficient way of writing this code without pointers **pointers**.

**Note: I'm a beginner that's why I'm asking for a solution without pointers.**

Comment: Strings are arrays, which you access via pointers. A pointer can be thought of as the address of a block of memory. They seem intimidating at first, but you may as well not shy away from them since you can't really get away from them in the end anyway.

Comment: For example, `strlen(name);` is actually passing in the pointer to the first element of `name` to `strlen`.

Comment: Yes I know but I really don't understand them now but I'm trying to. I just need to make this work without pointers just for now. @MadPhysicist

Comment: Why have you `number_of_words++;` after you counted how many words? That makes 5 but there are only 4 words.... Uh, you compensated for that later by using `while(counter < number_of_words - 1)`

Comment: I started the w form 0 so when the 3 spaces are added to 0 the number_of_words will be equal to 3 but there are four words so I add 1 to get the right number of words. @WeatherVane

Comment: There are 4 spaces. If you `printf("%d", number_of_words);` you'll find that says 5, but you actually only count to (5-1) later.

Comment: true sorry for that @WeatherVane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, trying to avoid pointers in C will be (very) hard. Just by their nature, arrays become pointers the instant you want to do anything useful with them. Array subscription is syntactic sugar over pointer arithmetic (`foo[2]` is the same as `*(foo + 2)`). Passing an array to a function will cause it to *decay* to a pointer to the first element.

You use pointers several times in your code, whether you realise it or not.

---

As for the code...

*Quick note: `size_t`, not `int`, is the appropriate type to use when working with memory sizes / indexing. I'll be using it in the "corrected" versions of the code, and you should try to use it in general, moving forward.*

The output is a bit confusing because everything is printed on a single line. Let's clean that up, and add some debugging information, like the length of each string you've stored.

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    printf("%zu [length: %zu]: ", x, strlen(full[x]));

    for (size_t y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        printf("%c", full[x][y]);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Now we get the output, across several lines (some duplicates collapsed for brevity), of:

```
0 [length: 5]: hello
1 [length: 0]:  world
2 [length: 0]:  from
3 [length: 0]:  jor
4 [length: 3]: dan
5 [length: 0]: 
...
19 [length: 0]:
```

From this we can see a few notable things.

- We have an additional, fifth "string", when we were only expecting four.
- Our first and fifth "strings" have the apparent correct length, whilst
- Our second through fourth "strings" have an apparent length of `0`, and would seem to include spaces.

The zero lengths mean some of our *arrays* are starting with the null-terminating byte (`'\0'`), and we are only seeing output because we manually walk the entirety of each array.

Note that most terminals will do "nothing" when a null character is to be printed, meaning we appear to skip directly to our "strings". We can better visualize what is happening by **always** printing something:

```
printf("%c", full[x][y] ? full[x][y] : '*');
```

In this case we print an asterisk when we encounter a null character, giving us the output:

```
0 [length: 5]: hello***************
1 [length: 0]: ***** world*********
2 [length: 0]: *********** from****
3 [length: 0]: **************** jor
4 [length: 3]: dan*****************
5 [length: 0]: ********************
...
19 [length: 0]: ********************
```

This very clearly shows where in memory our characters have been placed.

The primary issue is that in this loop

```
for (int j = end_word; j < start; j++) {
    full[counter][j] = name[j];
}
```

`j` is initialized to a position relative to the beginning of `name`, but is used to index a memory offset of `full`. Excluding our first substring, when `end_word` is `0`, this puts us farther and farther away from the zeroth index of each subarray, eventually crossing the borders between arrays.

This happens to work because 2D arrays in C are laid out contiguously in memory.

To fix this, we must copy our characters using a separate index that starts at zero for each subarray.

```
for (size_t j = end_word, k = 0; j < start; j++, k++) {
    full[counter][k] = name[j];
}
```

Now when we print our arrays out we can limit ourselves to our known `number_of_words` (`for (size_t x = 0; x < number_of_words; x++)`), giving us the output:

```
0 [length: 5]: hello***************
1 [length: 6]:  world**************
2 [length: 5]:  from***************
3 [length: 7]:  jordan*************
```

This looks roughly correct, but includes the preceding space in the "word". We can skip past these spaces by setting `end_word` to the *next character* instead:

```
start++;
end_word = start;
counter++;
```

Now our output looks properly split:

```
0 [length: 5]: hello***************
1 [length: 5]: world***************
2 [length: 4]: from****************
3 [length: 6]: jordan**************
```

Note that these are (now properly formatted) [null-terminated strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), and could be printed using the `%s` specifier, as in:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < number_of_words; x++)  
    printf("%zu [length: %zu]: %s\n", x, strlen(full[x]), full[x]);
```

---

Overall this is a bit fragile, as it requires the trailing delimiting space in order to work, and will create an empty string each time a delimiting space is repeated (or if the source string starts with a space).

---

As an aside, this similar example should showcase a straight-forward method for tokenizing a string, while skipping over all delimiters, and includes some important annotations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[30] = "hello world from jordan";
    char copies[20][30] = { 0 };
    size_t length_of_copies = 0;

    size_t hold_position = 0;
    size_t substring_span = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    do {
        /* our substring delimiters */
        if (name[i] == ' ' || name[i] == '\0') {
            /* only copy non-zero spans of non-delimiters */
            if (substring_span) {
                /* `strncpy` will not insert a null terminating character
                 * into the destination if it is not found within the span
                 * of characters of the source string...
                 */
                strncpy(
                    copies[length_of_copies],
                    name + hold_position,
                    substring_span
                );

                /* ...so we must manually insert a null terminating character
                 * (or otherwise rely on our memory being initialized to all-zeroes)
                 * */
                copies[length_of_copies++][substring_span] = '\0';
                substring_span = 0;
            }

            /* let's assume our next position will be the start of a substring */
            hold_position = i + 1;
        } else
            substring_span++;

        /* checking our character at the end of the loop,
         * and incrementing after the fact,
         * let's us include the null terminating character as a delimiter,
         * as we will only fail to enter the loop after processing it
         */
    } while (name[i++] != '\0');

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length_of_copies; i++)
        printf("%zu: [%s]\n", i + 1, copies[i]);
}
```